# Как изменять размеры root-элемента в зависимости от размеров окна?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть GUI на tkinter с картой. Выставлен начальный размер 800 на 600. Но когда я разворачиваю окно на весь экран - карта остается в прежнем размере. Как заставить сам root разворачиваться вместе с окном?

Код:

```
import json
import tkinter
import tkintermapview

# Определение дефолтных значений
DEFAULT_LATITUDE = 0.0
DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = 0.0
DEFAULT_USER_ID = "2000"

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry(f"{800}x{600}")
root.title("Finder Alert Button Map")
root.iconbitmap('ic_launcher_playstore.ico')

# Флаг для отслеживания открытого информационного окна
info_window_open = False


def get_address(coords):
    global info_window_open
    if not info_window_open:  # Проверяем, открыто ли уже информационное окно
        print("Coords: ", coords)
        adr = tkintermapview.convert_coordinates_to_address(coords[0], coords[1])
        print(adr.street, adr.housenumber, adr.postal, adr.city, adr.state, adr.country, adr.latlng)
        show_info(adr)
        info_window_open = True


def show_info(address):
    global info_window_open
    message = (
        f"{address.street}, {address.housenumber}\n"
        f"{address.postal} {address.city}\n"
        f"{address.state}, {address.country}\n"
        f"{address.latlng}"
    )
    info_window = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
    info_window.iconbitmap('ic_launcher_playstore.ico')
    info_window.configure(bg="lightblue")
    info_window.title("Address info")
    info_text = tkinter.Text(info_window, height=5, width=40)
    info_text.insert(tkinter.END, message, "center")
    info_text.tag_configure("center", justify="center")  # Конфигурируем тег для центрирования
    info_text.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)  # Запретить редактирование текста
    info_text.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    info_button = tkinter.Button(info_window, text="OK", command=lambda: close_info_window(info_window))
    info_button.pack(pady=(0, 10))


def close_info_window(window):
    global info_window_open
    window.destroy()
    info_window_open = False







map_widget = tkintermapview.TkinterMapView(root, width=800, height=600, corner_radius=0)
map_widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
map_widget.set_zoom(15)
map_widget.add_right_click_menu_command(label="Get address",
                                        command=get_address,
                                        pass_coords=True)

markers = {}  # Словарь для отслеживания маркеров по user_id


def write_default_values_to_json():
    """Записывает дефолтные значения в JSON-файл."""
    data_to_write = {
        "lat": DEFAULT_LATITUDE,
        "lon": DEFAULT_LONGITUDE,
        "user_id": DEFAULT_USER_ID
    }
    with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data_to_write, json_file, indent=2)


def on_closing():
    """Функция вызывается при закрытии главного окна."""
    write_default_values_to_json()
    root.destroy()


def create_marker(latitude, longitude, user_id):
    # Создаем маркер
    marker = map_widget.set_marker(latitude, longitude, command=remove_marker_and_path)
    marker.set_text(user_id)

    # Создаем путь и добавляем первую позицию
    path = map_widget.set_path([marker.position, (latitude, longitude)])
    path.add_position(latitude, longitude)

    # Возвращаем маркер и путь
    return marker, path


def update_map():
    try:
        with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
            data_read = json.load(json_file)

        latitude = data_read["lat"]
        longitude = data_read["lon"]
        user_id = data_read["user_id"]

        # Проверяем, изменились ли координаты
        if (latitude, longitude) != update_map.last_coordinates:
            # Сохраняем последние координаты
            update_map.last_coordinates = (latitude, longitude)

            if user_id not in markers:
                # Если для данного user_id еще нет маркера, создаем его и добавляем в словарь
                marker, path = create_marker(latitude, longitude, user_id)
                markers[user_id] = {'marker': marker, 'path': path}
            else:
                # Если маркер уже существует, обновляем его координаты
                marker, path = markers[user_id]['marker'], markers[user_id]['path']
                map_widget.set_position(latitude, longitude)
                marker.set_position(latitude, longitude)
                path.add_position(latitude, longitude)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File 'data.json' not found.")
        pass
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print("JSONDecodeError: File 'data.json' is empty or contains invalid JSON data.")
        pass
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"KeyError: Missing key {e} in 'data.json'.")
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
        pass
    root.after(2000, update_map)


# Инициализируем последние координаты как (0, 0)
update_map.last_coordinates = (0, 0)


def remove_marker_and_path(marker):
    if marker.text in markers:
        # Удаляем маркер и связанный с ним путь
        marker_info = markers.pop(marker.text)
        marker_info['marker'].delete()
        marker_info['path'].delete()


def button1_clicked(event):
    map_widget.set_tile_server("https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")


def button2_clicked(event):
    map_widget.set_tile_server("https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=ru&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga", max_zoom=22)


def button3_clicked(event):
    map_widget.set_tile_server("https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga", max_zoom=22)


# Создаем две кнопки
button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="OSM maps")
button1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='s')
button1.bind("<Button-1>", button1_clicked)

button2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Google maps")
button2.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='s')
button2.bind("<Button-1>", button2_clicked)

button3 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Google satellite")
button3.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='s')
button3.bind("<Button-1>", button3_clicked)

# Привязываем функцию on_closing к событию закрытия окна
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.after(1000, update_map)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: relheight, relwidth пробовали задать при установке map_widget?

Answer (score 1):

Решение было найдено, благодаря Сергей Кох. Достаточно установить для map_widget параметры relwidth=1.0 и relheight=1.0:

```
map_widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы реализовать изменение размеров `root`-элемента в зависимости от размеров окна, вы можете использовать обработчик событий изменения размеров окна. Вам нужно будет обновить размеры `root` при изменении размеров окна, чтобы они соответствовали новым размерам.

Вот как вы можете модифицировать ваш код:

1. Добавьте функцию для обновления размеров `root`:

   def update_root_size(event):
   root.geometry(f"{event.width}x{event.height}")
2. Привяжите эту функцию к событию изменения размеров окна:

   root.bind("", update_root_size)

Полный код с изменениями:

```
def update_root_size(event):
    root.geometry(f"{event.width}x{event.height}")

root.bind("<Configure>", update_root_size)


root.mainloop()
```

Теперь, когда вы изменяете размеры окна, `update_root_size` будет вызываться, и `root` будет обновляться в соответствии с новыми размерами окна.

вот полный код с изменением:

```
import json
import tkinter
import tkintermapview

DEFAULT_LATITUDE = 0.0
DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = 0.0
DEFAULT_USER_ID = "2000"

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry(f"{800}x{600}")
root.title("Finder Alert Button Map")
root.iconbitmap('ic_launcher_playstore.ico')

info_window_open = False

def get_address(coords):
    global info_window_open
    if not info_window_open:
        adr = tkintermapview.convert_coordinates_to_address(coords[0], coords[1])
        show_info(adr)
        info_window_open = True

def show_info(address):
    global info_window_open
    message = (
        f"{address.street}, {address.housenumber}\n"
        f"{address.postal} {address.city}\n"
        f"{address.state}, {address.country}\n"
        f"{address.latlng}"
    )
    info_window = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
    info_window.iconbitmap('ic_launcher_playstore.ico')
    info_window.configure(bg="lightblue")
    info_window.title("Address info")
    info_text = tkinter.Text(info_window, height=5, width=40)
    info_text.insert(tkinter.END, message, "center")
    info_text.tag_configure("center", justify="center")
    info_text.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
    info_text.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    info_button = tkinter.Button(info_window, text="OK", command=lambda: close_info_window(info_window))
    info_button.pack(pady=(0, 10))

def close_info_window(window):
    global info_window_open
    window.destroy()
    info_window_open = False

def update_root_size(event):
    root.geometry(f"{event.width}x{event.height}")

root.bind("<Configure>", update_root_size)

map_widget = tkintermapview.TkinterMapView(root, width=800, height=600, corner_radius=0)
map_widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
map_widget.set_zoom(15)
map_widget.add_right_click_menu_command(label="Get address",
                                        command=get_address,
                                        pass_coords=True)

markers = {}

def write_default_values_to_json():
    data_to_write = {
        "lat": DEFAULT_LATITUDE,
        "lon": DEFAULT_LONGITUDE,
        "user_id": DEFAULT_USER_ID
    }
    with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data_to_write, json_file, indent=2)

def on_closing():
    write_default_values_to_json()
    root.destroy()

def create_marker(latitude, longitude, user_id):
    marker = map_widget.set_marker(latitude, longitude, command=remove_marker_and_path)
    marker.set_text(user_id)
    path = map_widget.set_path([marker.position, (latitude, longitude)])
    path.add_position(latitude, longitude)
    return marker, path

def update_map():
    try:
        with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
            data_read = json.load(json_file)

        latitude = data_read["lat"]
        longitude = data_read["lon"]
        user_id = data_read["user_id"]

        if (latitude, longitude) != update_map.last_coordinates:
            update_map.last_coordinates = (latitude, longitude)

            if user_id not in markers:
                marker, path = create_marker(latitude, longitude, user_id)
                markers[user_id] = {'marker': marker, 'path': path}
            else:
                marker, path = markers[user_id]['marker'], markers[user_id]['path']
                map_widget.set_position(latitude, longitude)
                marker.set_position(latitude, longitude)
                path.add_position(latitude, longitude)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File 'data.json' not found.")
        pass
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print("JSONDecodeError: File 'data.json' is empty or contains invalid JSON data.")
        pass
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"KeyError: Missing key {e} in 'data.json'.")
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
        pass
    root.after(2000, update_map)

update_map.last_coordinates = (0, 0)

def remove_marker_and_path(marker):
    if marker.text in markers:
        marker_info = markers.pop(marker.text)
        marker_info['marker'].delete()
        marker_info['path'].delete()

button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="OSM maps")
button1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='s')
button1.bind("<Button-1>", button1_clicked)

button2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Google maps")
button2.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='s')
button2.bind("<Button-1>", button2_clicked)

button3 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Google satellite")
button3.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='s')
button3.bind("<Button-1>", button3_clicked)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

root.after(1000, update_map)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не работает в данном случае. Окно уходит в бесконечный цикл переоткрытий.